java.lang.InterruptedException: null on tridion sites publish action when added storage extension
I am working on deployer storage extension on tridion sites 10 and dxd 12, while added storage extension to deployer it started throwing interrupted exception, following is error trace
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786 DEBUG [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Could not gracefully shutdown workerService - forcing shutdown
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786 DEBUG [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Queue [Id=ContentQueue]. Worker service shutdown finished
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786  INFO [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Stopping command queue poller for queue: com.sdl.delivery.deployer.queue.filesystem.FSDeployerQueue@3e1e44a5
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786 DEBUG [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Queue [Id=CommitQueue]. Attempting to shutdown workerService
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786 DEBUG [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Queue [Id=CommitQueue]. Worker service shutdown finished
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786  INFO [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Stopping command queue poller for queue: com.sdl.delivery.deployer.queue.filesystem.FSDeployerQueue@25c32b60
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786 DEBUG [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Queue [Id=PrepareQueue]. Attempting to shutdown workerService
2024-12-13 10:51:04.786 DEBUG [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Queue [Id=PrepareQueue]. Worker service shutdown finished
2024-12-13 10:51:04.792 ERROR [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [pool(Queue Workers - ContentQueue)--thread-1] c.s.d.d.w.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller  : Could not process command: JSONCommand{verbs=[Content], action='TridionBootstrap', binaryIds=[tcm_0-5097594-66560.Content.zip], executionId='tcm:0-5097594-66560', properties={}}

java.lang.InterruptedException: null
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1048)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:242)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:258)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:263)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.$anonfun$result$1(package.scala:223)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:57)
    at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:146)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.engine.pipeline.actor.AkkaProcessingService.process(AkkaProcessingService.scala:38)
    at com.sdl.delivery.deployer.worker.queue.impl.CommandQueuePoller.lambda$submitWork$1(CommandQueuePoller.java:143)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2024-12-13 10:51:04.831  INFO [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.t.s.management.StorageManagerImpl      : Shutting down DAO Factory of type: 'class com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory'
2024-12-13 10:51:04.831  INFO [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.t.s.management.StorageManagerImpl      : Shutting down DAO Factory of type: 'class com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory'
2024-12-13 10:51:04.831  INFO [deployer-service,-,-,staging] 2284 --- [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] c.t.s.management.StorageManagerImpl      : Shutting down DAO Factory of type: 'class com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory'

the above error is stopping deployer while publish.
please suggest.

In my experience, this error often masks the root cause of the issue. The simplest way to uncover the actual problem is to run the deployer from PowerShell using the ./start script. This will allow you to see what's really happening.

Thanks Phil, we were able to figure out the root cause when deployer service started from ./start script.

Care to share what the root cause was, in case it can help others?
